# Spectrum of the difference of two commuting operators

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I am looking for a way to prove that for two commuting, linear and bounded operators $A,B$ acting on a Banach space $X$
$$\sigma(A-B)\subset\sigma(A)-\sigma(B)$$

I have already found a proof that "simply" applies results from Gelfand theory. This however requires extensive knowledge on Banach Algebras.

That is why I would be happy to get some different ideas for ways of proving the statement above.